# Need to calculate distance,height,width of a room using android camera

Tags: android, camera, height, width, distance

Sorry for my question.I have done quite a bit research but unfortunately after over 50 hour i am not able to get any of the working code.I want to develop https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.aboy.measure 
this type of functionality.Not the exact one.I just need to calculate distance between my camera and one object.also i have to find the width and length of a wall in a room.Its very important for me. It would be nice if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: "working source code" - this isn't a "haz the codes" site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to measure height, width and distance of object using camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera)

Comment: I meant the algorithm duffymo

Comment: Dear g00dy..I just want an algorithm.or the pseudo code.Please understand.All the stuffs are available are theoretical based.I need sample codes.Please understand

Comment: As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061448/2274885 : a reference object of which you know the exact dimensions is very helpful with this kind of thing.

Comment: Dear M.Bennett..Again to mentioned ur article..For that concept their is problem to find the h height.As it is variable.There is no way that i can assume that height.So,this theory is also not working

Comment: @FunLove, Have you solved your problem.I am facing the same issue.Please help me.Thanks in advance.. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to measure that accurate, but I think that articles can help you : [Determine Android Device's Camera Height and Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772243/determine-android-devices-camera-height-and-width), [How to measure height, width and distance of object using camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera), [Is it possible to measure distance to object with camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588485/is-it-possible-to-measure-distance-to-object-with-camera), [how can we measure distance between object and android phone camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949777/how-can-we-measure-distance-between-object-and-android-phone-camera) .

Citation from http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=67531 :

> It isn’t an easy task. You may need to combine more than 1 image to do
>   this. Or you need to know physical dimensions of the object you’re
>   taking a picture of. I suggest looking at [this](http://opencv.org/) library (recently also
>   available for Android, although I haven’t used it for it). You’ll be
>   particularly interested in [3d reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html), I presume. There are
>   some [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) to get you started with this. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your view Ty221.I have already gone through with this.The First article is not useful.As i want only the object distance from my camera to the object.Others are theoretical.If u can help me regarding the pseudo code it will be so much helpful for me

Comment: I am stuck in my progress..If you guide me it will be very helpful for me.its quite complex using openCV to find the distance.I have come to a solution and that is to find the focal length and angle of elevation.I am assuming my device camera is typically 5t high.Now i am stuck to find the angle of elevation and my device camera focul length :(