# Get Android device's camera size using android.hardware.camera2

Tags: android, camera, hardware

After reading up on how to determine the camera's supported sizes, it is clear that all relevant questions ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772243/determine-android-devices-camera-height-and-width)) are referring to the old `android.hardware.camera` which has now been deprecated.

How to you retrieve the current device's supported resolutions using the new `camera2` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getHighResolutionOutputSizes(int format)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getHighResolutionOutputSizes(int)), [getInputSizes(int format)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getInputSizes(int)) and [getOutputSizes(int format)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputSizes(int)) seem to contain what you're looking for.